# access Node.JS Express static directory from different routes

Tags: node.js, express, web

I have a NodeJS with Express and I'm using Gulp to build the app

`public` folder is source code folder for script and style files,
and `dist` is a folder for Gulp output that contains all css, js, ejs files

my file structure is this:

```
|-app.js
|-server.js
|-routes
    |-loginRoute.js
    |-appRoute.js
|-views
    |-loginViews
        |-login.ejs
    |-index.ejs
|-public
    |-scripts
        |-script files...
    |-style
        |-css files...
|-dist
    |-scripts
        |-script files...
    |-css
        |-css files...
    |-loginViews
        |-login.ejs
    |-index.ejs
```

I set `dist` folder as a static folder like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

and all .ejs views served from `dist` folder.

When I try to access `http://localhost:8080/login` Express render `login.ejs` that placed in `dist/login` folder, and I got an error when the page tries to load script and css files that those files don't exist under `http://localhost:8080/login/somefile`

But, when views served from `views` folder, and static folder set like

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and I try to access to `http://localhost:8080/login`, Express render `login.ejs` that placed in `views/login` folder, the browser able to load css and script files from the static folder

Comment: Do you try to set all styles and js folders static? I think that this thing will resolve your problem. Always when I use .ejs and express, I set all folder statics, one by one and it works